# How do I implement my minecraft server's banned-players.json to html automatically/effectively?

Tags: html, json, minecraft

I have a problem figuring out how to add the json file to the website so it can update automatically.

The only way I have worked this was copy+pasting the code into a variable itself

```js
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
  var bannedPlayers = [{
      "uuid": "-",
      "name": "foobar",
      "created": "2019-04-01 13:37:52 -0700",
      "source": "-",
      "expires": "forever",
      "reason": "Banned by an operator."
    } //theres more than this
  ]
  var col = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < bannedPlayers.length; i++) {
    for (var key in bannedPlayers[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

  var table = document.createElement("table");

  var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < bannedPlayers.length; i++) {

    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell.innerHTML = bannedPlayers[i][col[j]];
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="CreateTableFromJSON()" value="Create Table From JSON" />
  <p id="showData"></p>
</body>
```

The problem is obviously, I do not want to nor does my other operators want to copy and paste everysingle time we ban someone (and the fact that i grabbed most of the code above from the internet-im a noob@html)! Another way i have tried to solve this is harder to explain, but is to change the whole json file itself

```js
function load() {
  var mydata = JSON.parse(data);


  var div = document.getElementById('data');

  for (var i = 0; i < mydata.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<p id=" + i + ">" + mydata[i].name + "</p>" + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.json"></script>

<body onload="load()">
  <div id="data">

  </div>
</body>
```

This is the abc.json file (stand-in for banned-players.json for now)

```js
data = '[{"uuid": "redacted", "name": "foobar", "created": "2019-04-01 13:37:52 -0700", "source": "operateor", "expires": "forever", "reason": "Banned by an operator." }]'
// theres more than that bracket
```

The problem with this is that it only shows the one column that i choose, and i dont know how to organize it in a table.

My question: is there a way i can not tamper with the json file itself while it hopefully automatically updates on my html page?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you to use a plugin to manage your punishments (bans, kicks, mutes, ...) which stores the data in a database. Then you are able to query these information with e.g. `PHP` using e.g. `mysqli`.

When you don't want/can use a plugin to manage this and have to read the information from the `banned-players.json`, you need to manage to get the information from the file to the website.

To achieve this, you have to ask yourself the question: Is the `banned-players.json` file stored on the same machine, where the website is running?

---

If so, you only need to give the webserver access to read the file and actually read the file using some server side code (you can use e.g. `PHP` for this).

The webserver is mostly running with the user called `www-data`. Use the `chmod` or `chown` command to give the user access to the file. E.g. `chmod 774 banned-players.json` will cause that every user on your machine can read the file, and only selected users can write to the file.

Once you have done this, you can read the input of the file using e.g. `PHP` and print the output in your `JavaScript` code.

You can use this code, to read the file:

```
<?php
$filePath = "/path/to/file/banned-players.json";
$myfile = fopen($filePath, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$data fread($myfile, filesize($filePath));
fclose($myfile);
echo $data;
?>
```

Note, that the `PHP` code will be executed on server side, before the page is displayed in the users browser!

Using this, your `Javascript` code could look like this:

```
function CreateTableFromJSON() {
  var bannedPlayers = 
<?php
  $filePath = "/path/to/file/banned-players.json";
  $myfile = fopen($filePath, "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $data = fread($myfile, filesize($filePath));
  fclose($myfile);
  str_replace("data = '", "", $data);
  str_replace("'", "", $data);
  echo $data;
?>
  var col = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < bannedPlayers.length; i++) {
    for (var key in bannedPlayers[i]) {
...
...
...
```

---

If the file is not stored on the same machine, you need to manage to synchronize the file with the other machine, or create a webservice, or any other kind of service, which provides the information from the file for the other machine.